# How to escape SSL error in webview windows phone8

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, ssl, webview, wininet

I have to update my code to handle the ssl certificate error.What basicaly i want is when the usser is redirected to webview page with the url, and if i get a SSL error over there i need to catch it and provide user with two options in message box to 1) skip the error and process the functionality and 2) cancel the transaction and return to previous page.

Here is my webview method which is doing the work for me

```
   private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string dummyString = "";
            foreach (string item in paymentDetails.Keys)
            {
                dummyString = dummyString + item + "=" + paymentDetails[item] + "&";
            }
            string postData = dummyString.TrimEnd('&');

            PaymentOptions _payment = new PaymentOptions();
            webview.Navigate(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData), "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve the issue.Like can anyone guide me through in how can we do this.Till now i a mjust navigating the url to the paymentgateway and capturing the succes response.